# How to replace some special characters from user input for different Python platforms

Tags: python, escaping

I need to replace some special characters from user input for different platform  (i.e. Linux and Windows) using Python. Here is my code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        rname1 = request.POST.get('react')
```

Here I am getting the user input by post method. I need to the following characters to remove from the user input (if there is any).

```
1- Escape or filter special characters for windows,   ( ) < >  * ‘  = ? ; [ ] ^ ~ ! . ” % @ / \ : + , ` 

2- Escape or filter special characters for Linux, { }  ( ) < >  * ‘  = ? ; [ ]  $ – # ~ ! . ” %  / \ : + , `
```

The special characters are given above. Here I need to remove for both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Python strings have a built in method `translate` for substitution/deletion of characters. You need to build a translation table and then call the function.

```
import sys
if "win" in sys.platform:
    special = """( ) < >  * ‘  = ? ; [ ] ^ ~ ! . ” % @ / \ : + , `""".split()
else:
    special = """{ }  ( ) < >  * ‘  = ? ; [ ]  $ – # ~ ! . ” %  / \ : + , `""".split()

trans_dict = {character: None for character in special}
trans_table = str.maketrans(trans_dict)
print("Lo+=r?e~~m ipsum dol;or sit!! amet, consectet..ur ad%".translate(trans_table))
```

Will print `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ad`.

If you want to use a replacement character instead of deleting, then replace `None` above with the character. You can build a translation table with specific substitutions, `{"a": "m", "b": "n", ...}

Edit: The above snippet is indeed in Python3. In Python2 ([TiO](https://tio.run/##bY5LCsIwFEXnWcVrarG1tQWH/boAcQNWsUiqgeZDEpEiZus1HRQceEcP7jvcI0fzEHw3TZRJoQzoUaPlNIryO6I94BflGCif21QOnemFYjkCFy3JjXYDVIAxDqOy3qyrpjidL9YL9lmbV8nVFYgMmvwB3p8fZLX1rZfiwFHxzOj55yBi1RBrs9YvawZU6jB6Fgwj6eQWx9SojmvnRUKdwFFwkiw7EZqmLw)) it's [easier to delete characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
>>> import sys
>>> import string
>>> if "win" in sys.platform:
...    special = """()<>*'=?;[]^~!%@/\:=,`"""
... else:
...    special = """{}()<>*'=?;[]$-#~!."%/\:+"""
...
>>> s = "Lo+r?e~~/\#<>m ips()u;m"
>>> string.translate(s, None, special)
'Lorem ipsum'
```

Note that I've substituted `‘` with `'` and similarly replaced `”` with `"` because I think you're only dealing with ascii strings.

Comment: Its throwing some error. `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file system.py on line 13, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`. Actually this `if "win" in sys.platform:` line error is coming.

Comment: again see this line `type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'`. Its also coming.

Comment: I am using `python 2.7` I think that is the code for python3.